# Given $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^2x}{x}=0$, evaluate $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

> Given that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\left(\sin x\right)^2}{x}=0$, find the limit $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x}$.
>
> a. $1\quad$ b. $0\quad$ c. $\frac12\quad$ d. The limit does not exist

New to Calculus, and these trig questions really trip me up. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that $1-\cos x=2\sin^2\left(\dfrac x2\right)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint:**
$$
(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x) = 1-\cos^2(x) = \sin^2(x)
$$

**more hints:**

> \begin{align*} \frac{1-\cos x}{x} = \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x(1+\cos x)} \end{align*}

> $\cos$ is continuous in $0$.

**solution:**

> \begin{align*} \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x(1+\cos x)} = \underbrace{\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}}_{=0} \cdot \underbrace{\frac{1}{1+\cos 0}}_{=\frac{1}{2}} = 0\end{align*}

**edit:**
The most important properties (and much more) are listed for example at the [wikipedia article about sine and cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions). As for what I used: The first equations just follows from the fact $(a-b)(a+b) = a^2-b^2$ (which has nothing to do with trig). The second equation follows from $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x =1$. While this might look surprising at first, this is something you are probably familiar with but just don't recognize. You can view $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ as the lengths of the sides of a right triangle with a hypotenuse length of $1$. Then it follows from the Pythagorean theorem. But this is also stated on wikipedia, there is also a nice visualization of sine and cosine on the unit circle.

Comment: I think I am missing fundamental trig knowledge. I do not know what values cos x and sin x are. I know how to calculate these angles with a right-triangle, but seeing them in this format is completely new to me.. Any advice?

Comment: @Vellutante I added some further information at the end of my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{1-\cos x}x=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin^2\left(\dfrac x2\right)}{x/2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(sinx)^2}{x}=0$
This is universally true.

Also, $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(1-cosx)}{x}= \lim_{x\to0}\frac{(1-cosx)}{x^2}*x$$
$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{2}*x=0$$

This is because of the standard limit:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(1-cosx)}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Did you mean $x^2$ where you wrote $x$ in the denominator in the last line?

Comment: Yes...I made an editing mistake there... I have corrected it... Thank you @J.W.Tanner

Comment: I think I am missing fundamental trig knowledge. I do not know what values cos x and sin x are. I know how to calculate these angles with a right-triangle, but seeing them in this format is completely new to me.. Any advice?

Comment: I would advise you to read texts, documents, books on trigonometry and atleast try to acquire the basic knowledge of trigonometry and perhaps also some basics of limits. As these questions cannot be solved without proper knowledge.... If you don't know trigonometry, then probably you did not understand the standard limits also, so please try to acquire some basics first. @Vellutante

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Once accordng to L'Hospital's rule
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to c} \frac{{f\left( x \right)}}{{g\left( x \right)}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to c} \frac{{f'\left( x \right)}}{{g'\left( x \right)}}$$

Therefore, once
$$\frac{d}{dx}(1-\cos(x)) = \frac{d}{dx}(1)-\frac{d}{dx}(\cos (x)) = 0-(-\sin(x)) = \sin(x)$$

and

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x) = 1$$

So $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{1-\cos(x)}{x} = \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin(x)}{1} = 0$